# passing data from controller to model in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla2.5

I am developing a joomla 2.5 component where I need to pass data from **controller** to **model**. The controller is receiving data from url. I find that controller is getting the value properly. Now I need to move that value to model from controller. From different post I have found a snippet of code for controller like below.

```
$datevalue = JRequest::getVar('day',$day); //receiving value from view
$item = JRequest::setVar('day',$datevalue); //setting variable

$model =& $this->getModel('WeeklyProgram'); //assign model
$model->setState('dayVar', $item); // assign value for model
```

The problem is that I don't know how to receive this value 'dayVar' from model. Can anybody help me on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Please, stop assigning objects by reference. Since PHP 5.0 that practices is considered harmful.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will remove reference.

Comment: To learn more, you can watch these two videos on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YZIBWQr_yk and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxxIXPc9IR8

Answer (score 1):

Use following things

In Modal

```
class CommunityModelCevent extends JCCModel
{
var $membersCount   = null;

    function getMembersCount($value) {
    $this->membersCount = $value // set your value here 15 

    // Now you can access this variable into model

    }
}
```

In controller

```
$ceventModel    = CFactory::getModel( 'cevent' );       
$membersCount   = $ceventModel->getMembersCount(15);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this . First you make get and set function in the model.Second load the model in the controller and simply pass the values to setter function.Example as follows:

updateratings.php---this is my model

```
class RatingManagerModelUpdateRatings extends JModelLegacy
    {
     public $data;

    public function get_data(){
    $data=$this->data;
    return $data;
     }

     public function set_data($data){
          $this->data=$data;
     }

    }
```

Controller.php
    class RatingManagerController extends JControllerLegacy
    {

```
public function save_ratings(){

 $tips = JRequest::getVar('tips'); //get data from front end form
 $model = $this->getModel('UpdateRatings'); //load UpdateRatings model
 $model->set_data($tips); //update setter function of model
 $res=$model->get_data(); // retrieve getter function
  //print_r($res);

} 

 }
```